# Stop escaping forward slash in bash variables

Tags: regex, bash, grep, escaping, user-input

I am having trouble with expanding variables and ignoring their forward slashes.

I have written a simple script that finds text in my git repository and replaces it with other text. This works fine, but now I want to expand it using regex. This shouldn't be too much of a problem since both git grep and sed support regex. However, when I try to use regex in my input variables the forward slashes are removed which ruins the script.

If I run `git grep "\bPoint"` in the terminal I will get many results. However, I can't figure out how to get the same results when I use user input in my script. The `git grep` file will change my input to `bPoint` instead of `\bPoint`, and won't find any results to give to sed.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script allows you to replace text in the git repository without damaging
# .git files. 

read -p "Text to replace: " toReplace
read -p "Replace with: " replaceWith

git grep -l ${toReplace}

# The command I want to run
#git grep -l "${toReplace}" | xargs sed -i "s,${toReplace},${replaceWith},g"
```

I've tried a lot of different combinations of quotations, but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: That's not a forward slash, it's a backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `read -r`. As per `help read`:

> `-r`       do not allow backslashes to escape any characters

**Examples:**

```
# without -r
read -p "Text to replace: " toReplace && echo "$toReplace"
Text to replace: \bPoint
bPoint

# with -r
read -rp "Text to replace: " toReplace && echo "$toReplace"
Text to replace: \bPoint
\bPoint
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, use double-quotes around variable references (e.g. `git grep -l "${toReplace}"`) to avoid unexpected word splitting and/or wildcard expansion.